# How to define a variable without assign any value to it

Tags: matlab

`vo` is the upper limit of an integration expression and this is the variable that I want to predefine as a variable without value since it is the variable I am trying to solve for.

Everything else is defined.

```
%//a object's velocity is changing as a function of sine, the full cycle is 0=>speed=>0

vt=-((speed/2)*cos((2*pi/t0)*t)-(speed/2)))

%//integrate vt function so I can get distance which has given

distance=int(vt,t,0,t0)

%//the last step is I need to find how long does it takes the object to finish a full cycle of movement

time=solve(eqn,t0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `syms` command in MATLAB.  The `syms` is part of the symbolic math toolbox and you can predefine "variables" without explicitly solving for them.  They form a part of the mathematics expression that you want.

Once you formulate the equation you want, you can use `solve` (as you have already used in your post) to solve the variable for you.

Comment: I tried, and this showed up.Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in sym/int (line 124)
   rSym = mupadmex('symobj::intdef',f.s,x.s,a.s,b.s,options);

Error in opopo (line 45)
eq1=int(vt,t,0,t0);

Comment: You should probably show us the rest of your code so I can give you a more detailed answer